# Embed Code scroll not working on ios responsive devices

Tags: ios, iphone, css, responsive-design, responsive

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

tried with this code, still not working. It's fine on every other devices, it's fine in MAC as well, only the problem is on ios responsive devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add overflow-scrolling to parent div. Check the below demo

```css
   .wrap {
      width: 320px;
      height: 500px;
      position: relative;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch !important;
      overflow-y: auto !important;
      border: 2px solid #ddd;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    iframe {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border: none;
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <iframe class="iframe" src="https://theimpossiblecool.tumblr.com/"></iframe>
  </div>
```